# Java code - how to set object variable

Tags: java

I am just learning and would like to know about a piece of code that sets the object variable.

What is the correct way to set object variable bfield in the follwoing test class?

```
public class test {
private String afield;

private String bfield;

public test() {

buildList();

}

public void buildList() {

    some code to derive and populate afield.

    this.bfield = this.afield;   //  ( 1)

    setBfield(afield);  // (2) say getter and setters do exist

    bfield = afield;  //  (3)
}
```

What is the right way to do? I soption 1 OK or option 2?

Comment: They all look correct to me...

Comment: Resisting an huge urge to downvote the question, I have to say, use Getter and Setter .

Comment: But if the setter method does something other than just setting the value (e.g. it might fire a `BFieldChangedEvent` or something like that) then you'd probably wan't to use the setter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of the three will work, of course.

I generally don't like option 1, unless i'm differentiating between an instance member and an argument.  For example, `public void buildList(String bfield) { this.bfield = bfield; }`.  `this.everything` is extra noise; if you don't need it, all it does is give the bugs more code to hide in.  :)

Option 2 is more future-proof; if ever you change things so that something else has to be set along with `bfield` (or if `bfield` doesn't need a backing field at all -- for instance, if setting it should set something on a sub-object), you'll be glad you called `setBfield` -- cause you won't have a dozen places to change code that sets `bfield`.  Basically, if you need and already have a `setBfield` method, i'd recommend using it in most cases.

If you have a field you know will always be contained within the object itself, and is independent of other fields, option 3 is typically faster.  Plus, you don't have to create a setter (read: pollute your interface), if you don't want outside code to be able to set `bfield` as well.

Answer (score 3):

setter/getters are more preferable because you can encapsulate some processing in those accessor methods too

---

**Also See**

- [why-use-getters-and-setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

Answer (score -2):

Use eclipse! Let it do some work for you.
Create a class Test like this.

```
public class Test {
   private String afield;
   private String bfield;
}
```

and then do these:

- right click -> select 'Source' -> Generate constructor
- right click -> select 'Source' -> Generate constructor with fields
- right click -> select 'Source' -> Generate getters / setters

done :) and do lookup for java bean convention. your code would freak out any java exp dev! :)

Comment: Thanks everybody. I will go with Getter and Setters but at the same time let me aks - if I am comapring these two variables, I think for the clarity point of view it will make more sense to say     {this.aField == this.bField}.     Correct me if I am wrong, please.

Comment: @Peter: It doesn't help clarity much if `afield` and `bfield` are not locals (or arguments); then it's just noise.